# Some warning texts on Stack Apps are hard to read

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

On [Stack Apps](http://www.stackapps.com), some warning texts are grey on orange and are hard to read.

Like this one:
[image]

But NOT this one:
[image]

Comment: As a kid, I once had a "101 experiments" book. It only had 100 experiments inside, but the cover was experiment 1: red text on a blue background, making your head explode. (Or, as the book described: making one see lightning flashes like in a thunderstorm.) That first screenshot reminds me of that!